# how to get the following fields using Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

> Address : AddressId, AddressLine, City, StateProvince, CountryRegion,
>   PostalCode
>
> Customer: customerId, NameStyle, title, firstname, middlename,
>   lastname, companyname, salesperson.
>
> CustomerAddress: customerid, addressid, addresstype.

I need to show:

> CustomerId, FirstName, MiddleName, AddressType, AddressLine1, City,
>   StateProvince, CountryRegion

on a single table.

so far I have tried:

```
select customer.CustomerId, FirstName, MiddleName, AddressType
    from customer inner join CustomerAddress
        on customer.customerid = customeraddress.customerid
```

but I still don't know how to get the rest of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat the join trick for the other table. I've added table aliases as well. They will make your query more compact, while still being able to use a table indicator for each field, without cluttering the field list too much.

```
select 
  c.CustomerId, 
  c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, 
  ca.AddressType, a.City, a.PostalCode
from 
  customer c
  inner join CustomerAddress ca
        on c.customerid = ca.customerid
  inner join Address a
        on a.addressid = ca.addressid
```

Comment: You're missing the table alias for `CustomerAddress`. :)

Comment: Thanks, fixed. :) Notepad++ has poor query validating capabilities. ;)